# Is the "Trash" bin an application or a directory/folder?

Tags: trash

If a simple directory, is it possible to edit links to it so they now point toward a different directory? A different directory that will perform the same tasks as the original "Trash" folder normally would (system recognizes it as the "Trash" folder)?

Comment: It is effectively an application (albeit a specialized one) that in some ways pretends to be a folder.  Muck with it at your peril, since it no doubt uses all sorts of specialized features.

Comment: What OS are you asking for (Linux/Mac/Windows); what specifically are you trying to accomplish? Depending on your OS, you're 'trash' is typically a system folder that get's handled differently (as @DanielRHicks alluded to). That said, the question is 'why' are you trying to move links in your trash 'folder' vs. just permanently deleting what's in your trash? Is your trash taking up too much space? Would you just like to relocate where the OS put's the system 'trash' folder for other reasons? Not negating anything, your question is too broad to elicit a viable answer, narrowing scope helps :)

Comment: @txtechhelp Agreed - I'll try to refine my question.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what operating system you're using.

In windows, it is a folder called RECYCLER(XP) or $Recycle.Bin(7) that resides on the root on every drive and has special access permissions. On top of that, the link on the desktop is a folder with a special value behind it (something like: Recycle Bin.{249689602906904-49286924-9864290} (I'd have to look up the right value, but this is also different for every windows version)

On the Mac it is an application.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to Linux, it's "in between", more or less - so it's a very good question.
From the application side, it's part of the file manager applications of the desktop environment, like Gnome or KDE. 
From the directory perspective, roughly speaking, it's one directory per file system, or really one per file system and user.

It may be interesting to have a tool just in between the application- and the filesystem perspective: a command line tool to user the "Trash".
Take a look at the package `trash-cli` (Ubuntu/Debian) for this.